# How to insert a pointer list into a pointer-pointer list?

Tags: list, pointers

Let's say I have these two lists with pointers.

```
list<Node **> open;
list<Node *> new_children;
```

I would like to fill the `list<Node **> open` with pointers that points to the `list<Node *> new_children`'s elements:

```
for (Node * n : new_children)
{
    open.emplace_front(&n);
}
```

After this, if I write out the elements of open:

```
for (auto o : open)
{
    (**o).dump();
}
```

I get the same element again and again. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it. When I iterate through `new_children`, every `Node * n` is a copy, which is not fortunate in case of pointers. So the correct way is to iterate through by reference, and create `Node **` pointers based on memory addresses. In my case another problem was that I created `Node **` in a function, so when I left the local scope, I got dangling pointers. For this the solution is to create new `Node **` with `new`. The `emplace_front()` actually works fine.

```
for (auto & n : new_children)
{
    Node ** new_open = new Node *(n);
    open.emplace_front(new_open);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is wrong :

```
for (Node * n : new_children)
{
    open.emplace_front(&n);
}
```

You need to use push_front:

```
for (Node * n : new_children)
{
    open.push_front(&n);
}
```

To do what you want.